# android menu icon do not display

Tags: menu, icons

i am using appcompat for my actionbar for 2.3。
i want collapseActionView when i click the options but not display at first。
![enter image description here][1]

As the img shows ,the menus do not show icons.
Could somebody help me .tks very much.
here are my codes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/zhuangtai"
    android:icon="@drawable/fa"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
    android:title="发状态"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/er"
    android:icon="@drawable/sao"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|withText"
    android:title="扫一扫"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|withText"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/sui"
    android:icon="@drawable/sui"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|withText"
    android:title="随份子"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|withText"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/haoyou"
    android:icon="@drawable/haoyou"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|withText"
    android:title="好友列表"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|withText"/>

</menu>
```

sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **android:showAsAction** introduced in API Level 11. In this case you are using Api level 9. Read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) tutorial. Its helps you.

Comment: i am using 8 ,i had deal compatibility with  "app:showAsAction='collapseActionView'",but the result was still not i would like.tks very much.

Comment: Try this tutorial(https://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionviews-to-your-actionbar/) you will get a idea.

Answer (score 0):

collapseActionView  The action view associated with this action item (as declared by android:actionLayout or android:actionViewClass) is collapsible.
Introduced in API Level 14.
So, one simple way is to remove collapseActionView

Comment: do you mean i should make a groupview to handle the icons titles.